# Actualizar solo un índice de un document en MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo un modelo de Mongoose en Node.js  que responde a un document en MongoDB

```
NAME: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
ADDED_BY: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
ADDED_DATE: { type: Date },
STATUS: { type: String, default: 'active' }
```

Ahorita hice un update de un document en específico directo en la consola de mongo, hice la siguiente instrucción

```
db.roles.update({NAME: "USER"}, {NAME: "USER_ROLE"});
```

Eso me actualizó el nombre de un document, pero me borró los índices `ADDED_BY, ADDED_DATE y STATUS.` No entiendo que pasó, cómo puedo hacer el update de un índice sin necesidad de mandar todos los parámetros de cada índice (Me estoy imaginando mi modelo de usuarios que tiene más de 50 índices )

Yo esperaba que se actualizara solo el nombre, pero al parecer cómo no le mandé los otros parámetros me los borró

Agradezco sus comentarios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás reemplazando el documento en vez de actualizarlo.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea actualizar 1 o más campos de un documento en MongoDB, usando el método `update`, de la siguiente manera  `db.roles.update({NAME: "USER"}, {NAME: "USER_ROLE"});`

Sin embargo, la instrucción no actualiza los campos, sino que reemplaza el documento.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para realizar la actualización del documento se usa el método `update`.

Según la documentación oficial de MongoDB, el método bien actualiza un documento según algún parámetro de actualización o reemplaza un documento por completo. El método recibe 3 parámetros, a saber `<query>, <update>, <options>`

`<query` este parámetro indica el criterio de selección del documento que deseamos actualizar. En este caso, actualizaremos un documento (el primero que consiga) cuyo campo `NAME` contenga el string `"USER"`

`<update>` si el parámetro update es un documento tipo `clave1: valor1, clave2: valor2, ... , claveN: valorN`, entonces el método `update()` reemplazará el documento con el documento que hemos pasado como parámetro. (Esto es lo que está sucediendo al hacer 
`db.roles.update({NAME: "USER"}, {NAME: "USER_ROLE"});`

Si deseamos actualizar uno o algunos campos específicos, entonces debemos usar un operador modificador de actualización. En este caso usaremos el operador `$set`, para indicarle a MongoDB que vamos a actualizar solamente los campos que están indicados. De esta forma la instrucción debería quedar asi:

```
db.roles.update({NAME: "USER"}, { $set: {NAME: "USER_ROLE"}});
```

Notemos que hemos encerrado `$set` dentro de llaves, a modo de `clave: valor`. Esto es muy importante, ya que si no lo hacemos de esta manera la instrucción fallará.

`<option>` este parámetro es un conjunto de opciones que podemos pasar al método `update()`. Por ejemplo, si deseamos actualizar más de un registro podemos indicarlo aqui, usando `{multi: true}`. De esta forma la actualización se realizará sobre todos los documentos que coincidan con nuestra `query`.

Para mayor información puedes consultar la documentación oficial de MongoDB:

[MongoDB - update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

[MongoDB - update - $set operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

[MongoDB - update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1)

Comment: Ciertamente como cuenta @Mauricio la verdad, entrar un poquito en mongoDB, puedes pasarte por mongo University que dan unos cursos espectaculares, eso si todos en ingles, y son gratuitos pero valen la pena y aprendes un montón, sobre mongoDB "@Alberto", te lo recomiendo.